# I've proven my language undecidable what is left to prove it Turing equivalent?

Tags: undecidability, turing-completeness

Let us say that I have a computation model $A$.  Let us also say that I have shown that $A$ can be simulated by a Turing machine.

I have not been able to prove that $A$ can simulate a Turing machine. In fact in trying to do so I have shown that doing so would require proving a notable unproven conjecture in mathematics.  I have shown that $A$'s halting problem is decidable iff this unproven conjecture is false.

This means if I were to show $A$ to be Turing complete I would prove the conjecture.  However it does not mean that if I proved $A$ to *not* be Turing complete I would disprove the conjecture.  Since (to the best of my knowledge) a language can be Turing undecidable and still remain weaker than a Turing machine.

I would like to show that the language is Turing equivalent iff the conjecture is true, but I have run into a block getting anywhere.  Since I doubt I will prove a conjecture of this caliber it seems worthless to try and simulate a Turing machine in $A$, but I don't know any non-constructive ways of proving Turing completeness.

Is there any useful strategy I could employ or relevant theorem I could use here?

---

<sub>In case of curiosity the unsolved problem I am dealing with is [the Skolem problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_problem)</sub>

Comment: How can a language *simulate* a Turing machine? A language is simply a set of words, not a computation model...

Comment: @dkaeae Ok yes it is a computation model with an associated language.

Comment: As you say, it can be that problems regarding $A$ are undecidable regardless of $A$ not being Turing-complete. That is the case, for instance, with PDAs (and CFGs). It is hard to suggest something without knowing the particulars of $A$.

Comment: @dkaeae Don't both PDAs and CFGs have a computable halting problem?  I mean if there is nothing to be done there is nothing to be done, I am just a bit confused by the comparason to PDAs and CFGs.

Comment: [I am not talking only about the halting problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Undecidable_problems)

Comment: @dkaeae I was clear on that. I am just missing the connection.  You may have to spell things out explicitly since am not understanding.

Comment: @dkaeae Wait isn't the halting problem computable for a linear bounded automaton?  Do you mean something else by LBA?

Comment: Sorry, brainslip :)  No, consider the computational model where each TM $M$ is mapped to a TM $M'$ where, on input $x$, $M'$ first tries to solve an undecidable (albeit semi-decidable) problem $H$ and, if $x \in H$, then simulates $M$. This is no longer Turing-complete since we do not have all RE languages (i.e., we only get $L(M') = H \cap L(M)$), and the halting problem for it is indeed undecidable since deciding it necessarily entails deciding $H$ (e.g., consider $M'$ for which $L(M) = \Sigma^\ast$).

Comment: Anyway, my point is (and you even said so yourself): The halting problem (or just about any other model-specific problem, really) being undecidable does not necessarily imply the model is Turing-complete. (And what you are trying to show is: $A$ Turing-complete $\iff$ conjecture true $\iff$ halting problem of $A$ not decidable.)